# Mezzanine framework blogcategory object display on templates

Tags: django, jinja2, templating, mezzanine

Please, how can I insert my blog category from my administration section on my templates. I have created the different blog category on mine administration section but I couldn't display it on my templates.

```
{% for blog_categories in blog_post.categories.all %}
    <li><a href="">{{ blog_categories }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```